# React Native built-in Modal is not visible while coming back to screen

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation-stack, react-modal, react-navigation-v6

I'm confused in this code little bit,
I've two screens, `MainScreen` and `FeedScreen` inside `NativeStackNavigator`,
where `initialScreenName`(screen which will be routed/render first) is `MainScreen`.

I've a modal nested inside `MainScreen` , and inside modal there is a button which will navigate to the `FeedScreen`, while navigating to `FeedScreen` , `Modal` was visible but while coming back to `MainScreen` , `Modal` is no more visible, and even not openning after clicking on "Show Modal" button...

Where `Modal` visibility is controlled by `state` variable, which is also true but still `Modal` is not visible...

Kindly point out what is going on here because according to me, `Modal` should be open while coming back to `MainScreen` from `FeedScreen`...

Here is code...

```
function MainScreen({navigation}){

const [modalVisibility, setModalVisibility] = useState(false)

return <View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}>I'm Main Screen...</Text>
          <Text>{String(modalVisibility)}</Text>
          <Button title='Show Modal' onPress={()=>setModalVisibility(true)} ></Button>

          <Modal visible={modalVisibility} onRequestClose={()=>setModalVisibility(false)}>
            <Text>I'm modal with visiblility {String(modalVisibility)}</Text>
            <Button title='Go to Feed' onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('FeedScreen')}/> 
          </Modal>
      </View>

}

function FeedScreen({navigation}) {
return <View>
      <Button title='Go to Main' onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("MainScreen")}></Button>
  </View>
}

function RootStackScreen() {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName='MainScreen'>

      <RootStack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen}/>
      <RootStack.Screen name="FeedScreen" component={FeedScreen}/>

  </RootStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the modalVisibility state is not exposed for the FeedScreen meaning the feedscreen cannot access the state, you can use a [context provider] [1] to expose that state to it.

```
[1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
```

Comment: Dear, I don't want to expose the modalVisibility state of "MainScreen" to the "FeedScreen", actually Modal (nested inside "MainScreen") is not visible while coming back to "MainScreen" from "FeedScreen",   there is no issue of modalVisibility state...

Comment: Yeah so because the MainScreen Component re-renders when you navigate to it, the value of modalVisibility state is initialized as false (because you set the default value to be false)

Comment: No, in stackNavigator, if routed screen in already available in the stack then it will not be re-rendered, I've have also checked it, in the above code, by printing modalVisibility state inside Text component, when I'm coming back to MainScreen, modalVisibility state is "true", means state of screen will be preserved when you will navigate to screen which is already present in the stack...

Comment: so does it work when you refresh the MainScreen?

Comment: you have `<Button title='Show Modal' onPress={()=>setModalVisibility(true)} ></Button>` in the MainScreen and `<Button title='Go to Feed' onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('FeedScreen')}/> `. remove the inconsistency and try to make them TouchableOpacity